# ESP32 PWM: How far can it go and how many things can I control per pin?

Tags: led, pwm, connector, esp32

I am designing lights lights for my fish tank and came up with the idea of using modular pucks of LEDs on small custom PCBs. This modular design would be easily scalable and reusable for future projects provided I can pass PWM signals to all the pucks. The LEDS will be driven by [this](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/BCR420UFDQ_BCR421UFDQ-1274616.pdf) and control will be from an ESP32 using PWM. My question is how feasible is it to use FPC/FFC cables to pass the same 10 channels of PWM to each puck. Currently, the plan is to run 4 pucks and I drew up this schematic to show what I mean with how PWM is being routed. Each circuit represents the red channel on each puck as an example. The distance between each puck should be about 4 inches in this design and the pucks themselves about that width as well or a bit smaller.

Is there an easy way to figure out exactly how many pucks I can run on a single PWM source for future use?
[image]

Comment: It is probably a lot easier to use LEDs with their own PWM like the ubiquitous WS2812B or the APA102.

Comment: Nah, the LEDs in question were chosen very specifically for this application.

Comment: You need another picture to clarify question "how feasible is it to use FPC/FFC cables to pass the same 10 channels of PWM to each puck".  Why are you sending 10 channels to each puck? Doesn't each puck only need 1 channel each? Are the pucks wired serially or in parallel? The answers to your questions depend on many factors -- To do well, you will have to understand wiring, fan-out, and layout. Good luck!